# Adding names for players Unity and Photon

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I'm using unity with photon and I'm having a problem making different names for every player that joins the room.
What I want to make is when a player joins the lobby i want him to take a name like

```
NewPlayer.gameobject.name = "Player " + the number of players that were in when he joined
```

. If you want any more information please reply to this post and ill inform you with your question. Thanks
I want the first player that joined the room his name to be "Player 1" the second "Player 2" and so on. I'm using photon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PhotonNetwork.NickName` which is synchronized across all clients in the room.
Than using `PhotonView` components attached to your players you use get the `Nickname` as:

```
var photonView = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
photonView.Owner.NickName;
```

Or based on your input you can use:

```
Player.ActorNumber
```

which is the `id` of the player in current room.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for responding! Ive tried that already but one problem that ive came to  is that in one instance of the game it will show up that im the player 1 but on the second instance it will show that im player 2 for some reason. Thanks for reading if you have any question please ask me!

Comment: How did you setup the Nicknames?

Comment: I have a game manager and on the void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer) i added   ```newPlayer.nickname = "Player " + PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.Length;```

Comment: Have you tried using: `Player.ActorNumber` ?

Comment: No i havent. Ill give that a try and try to learn what it does